# Are there SpaceChem Achievements?

Tags: achievements, spacechem

Are there achievements in SpaceChem?  When I look at the Steam page, it says I've earned 0/15, but doesn't list any.  Are they hidden until you stumble onto them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the 29th of April 2011 the game received an [update](http://www.spacechemthegame.com/researchnet-update).

Among other changes, all the 12 challenges previously only visible in the game, are now also visible Steam achievements, and there are an additional 3 achievements related to a [TF2 tie-in](http://www.teamfortress.com/post.php?id=5381&p=1).

This accounts for all 15 previously "empty" achievements on Steam.

---

Additionally, I was awarded Steam achievements for each completed Challenge without having to re-complete them, but I'm not sure of the mechanics in operation here to know how this is managed.

Comment: Unfortunately Android doesn't seem to support 'em. I had to copy the savefile to the Steam version and uploading it from the PC. (it's quite easy, though)

Answer (score 2):

You can see a list of achievements in the main screen, behind a button labelled 'Challenges' :)

Comment: In Steam, clicking Achievements brings you to a blank list. In-game, there's a 'Challenges' button, but being awarded those doesn't seem to have any connection to the Steam Achievements. Are you referring to something else, or?

Comment: @Tim Well, if there are achievements in the game, they're those.

Comment: I was specifically referring to Steam achievements; hence talking about the Steam achievements page.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you seeing this 0/15? The [SpaceChem store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/92800/) does not show it having any achievements (there would be an indicator of it below the "Single-player" one in the Game Details box).

Looking on the Steam forums for the game, the developer has said [that they'd be coming in a future update](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=21279137&postcount=4), but it doesn't look like the game has received any updates yet.

Comment: When I view the game in my library, under achievements it says Locked achievements: +15, and when I click "View All Achievements" it shows that I have 0/15